# How do I print a value of an array from WCF to form label?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, wcf

WCF generates 6 random lottery numbers, it returns them in an array on the wcf service, however I can't get it to print to a label on the form.

if I try to print it to a message box I get **"Value cannot be parsed as type int32"**

I tried creating a new array on the form the logic being like, form array = service array, since its returning an array the service should be an array shouldnt it? with that I get **Cannot implicitly convert type int to int[]**

here's where im at:

**IService**

```
public interface ILottoService
{

    [OperationContract]

    int[] GenerateLottoDrawNums();

    [OperationContract]

    int[] GenerateIrishLottoNums();

}
```

**Service**

```
 public int[] GenerateLottoDrawNums()
    {

        int min = 1;
        int max = 59;


        int[] randomNums = new int[6];


        Random rand = new Random();


        for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.Length; i++)
        {

            int tempNum = rand.Next(min, max); 

            while (IsDuplicate(tempNum, randomNums))
            {
                tempNum = rand.Next(7);
            }
            randomNums[i] = tempNum;

        }


        return randomNums;

    }

    public Boolean IsDuplicate(int tempNum, int[]randomNums)
    {
        foreach (var item in randomNums)
        {
            if (item == tempNum)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**Form**

```
    public partial class FrontEnd : Form
{
    LottoServiceReference.LottoServiceClient ws = null;
    public FrontEnd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrontEnd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ws = new LottoServiceReference.LottoServiceClient();
    }




    private void btnLottoDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int[] LottoDrawNums = new int[6];

            for (int i = 0; i < LottoDrawNums.Length; i++)
            {
                LottoDrawNums[i] = ws.GenerateLottoDrawNums();

                lblNum1.Text = String.Join(",", LottoDrawNums.ToString());

                MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", ws.GenerateLottoDrawNums()));

                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", ws.GenerateLottoDrawNums()));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }


    }

    }
}
```

}

Guessing I'm missing some [] or int[]?

My college tutor could not help, she referred me to you guys. Saying "It thinks its an int and it isn't. Try converting to String or List then printing that. She Googled and found a Stack Overflow question about converting but I didn't save it and can't find it at home.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < LottoDrawNums.Length; i++)
{
      lblNum1.Text = LottoDrawNums[0].ToString();
}
```

Set's only the first position of the array to the label.

Try String.Join
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
LblNum1.Text = String.Join(" , ", LottoDrawNums);
```

This will return somethingh like "3 , 45 , 6 , 54 , 56 , 7, 45 "

Also use it in  `MessageBox.Show(String.Join(" , ", ws.GenerateLottoDrawNums()));`

The GenerateLottoDrawNums and IsDuplicate methods work fine!

Comment: - I'm getting "'GenerateLottoDrawNums'. The value cannot be parsed as type int32" at MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", ws.GenerateLottoDrawNums())); any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: And this >> LblNum1.Text = String.Join(" , ", LottoDrawNums); , run's ok?

Comment: No, neither does anything. I've put it in a try catch. it's throwing exception but doesn't give any info that means anything to me. I've edited my form code above with where i'm at now. Am I write to create a new int[] array called **LottoDrawNums** then in the **for loop** have **LottoDrawNums[i] = ws.GenerateRandomNums()** i.e. form array **LottoDrawNums** = service array **RandomNums**?

Comment: Created a console app with the code, everything works fine >> https://github.com/parxal/lotonumbers/blob/master/LotoNumber/LotoNumber/Program.cs

Comment: Well after seeing that the code worked on a console app, I deleted the service reference and made a new one and now it works.The code is the same. Are you kidding me!? been at this over a week. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using StringBuilder, something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
For each element in array:
   sb.Append($"{element} ,")

String arrayAsString = sb.ToStirng(0, sb.Length-2);

LblNum1.Text = arrayAsString;
MessageBox.Show(arrayAsString);
```

Also, I think that you are missing Service Contract attribute above IService definition

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no problem with your project. I copy the code snippets and test it locally, works well. Maybe like the brother upstairs said, you may have lost something. I suggest you post more details about your project.
[image]
You could add the breakpoint to the server end and run the WCF service in debugging mode and check the return value. Or you add another method to test whether the service works well.

It should be noted that I host the WCF in a console application and use the basic binding.